# How do I make a .hover div stay open while the mouseover is still on the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First things first, a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7wfv8w8/

I have a navbar with a logo, search form and a `Categories` link. When somebody moves over it with the mouse, it should open the `wrapper-categories` div, which is `display: none;` by default.

I got it working, except the div is closing when you then move the mouse over the div that opened. I thought I could get it to stay open if I used `.navbar .toggle` to tell it that the parent is `.navbar` and it should stay open as long as the mouse is anywhere over that parent div.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">

<div class="wrapper-header">
 <ul>
     <li class="">Logo Here</li>
     <li class="">Search Here</li>
     <li class=""><a href="#" class="toggle">Categories</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-categories">
    Categories Here
</div>

</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(".navbar .toggle").hover(function (event){
               event.preventDefault();
               $(".wrapper-categories").slideToggle("fast");

});
```

Comment: If you change `$(".navbar .toggle")` to `$(".navbar")` it works because you're always within the navbar element. Otherwise the way you have it now it fails because `.wrapper-categories` is a sibling of `.toggle`. But then with that change the menu is triggered anytime the parent is hovered and not the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by binding the hover function to the element wrapping both `wrapper-header` and `wrapper-catagories`. This will cause the hoverOut to only be called when it leaves the wrapper for both elements. Keeping both of your required divs open.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7wfv8w8/5/

Comment: That works, but unfortunately it also opens when hovering on the logo or search part :(

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but change your class' to ID's and give this a go. Works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#toggle" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "#wrapper-categories" ).slideDown({
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
  }
);

var inArr = {toggle:false, wrapper-categories:false};

$('#toggle, #wrapper-categories').mouseover(function(){
    inArr [$(this).attr('id')] = true;
});

$('#toggle, #wrapper-categories').mouseout(function(){
    inArr [$(this).attr('id')] = false;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        if(!inArr.toggle && !inArr.wrapper-categories) { 
            $('#navArea').slideUp(500);
        }
    },100);
});
});
```